# Increase io priority on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, io, profiling, libtiff

Originally my producer function would just write the data, now I have a second thread that is responsible for writing the data. The producer function does a `memcpy` into a circular buffer and triggers the consumer thread to start writing.

When I use the 2 threaded scheme I get the desired thread isolation, program stability and the ability to variable computation before writing - but the io performance is 50% worse.

My theory is that there is some kind of priority that can be set per thread that I want to adjust. Is this possible.

I am using 2 SSDs in a RAID0 data stripping configuration.

[image: libTIFF io workflow]

Comment: You are doing an extra memory copy step. Of course it is slower.

Comment: @EJP yes, there is an extra memory copy but this would only matter if the code was somehow memory bound, or if the memory copy was serial with the file writing, this doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: What API are you using to write the data?

Comment: This might help (but I haven't read it): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454515.aspx

Comment: From a quick scan of MSDN search results, it seems that in order to have a high IO priority a thread must have a high priority.  You can use `SetThreadPriority` to do this.  However, I suspect that the problem might be memory and/or sector alignment of the write operation.  Consider using a set of sector- and page-aligned buffers rather than a single circular buffer.

Comment: You could also consider trying asynchronous IO rather than threading.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "io performance is 50% worse"? According to your resource monitor it is as high as it can be: disk queue is full, disk active time is 100%. If you mean write speed jumps - they have nothing to do with any possible thread priority. They are cause by disk head positioning due to files fragmentation, fs table modifications and so on.

Comment: The same 200 GB workload takes about 1.5x times as long. At first the rates are about the same but then one starts to lag behind. That is the first dozen or so gigabytes take the same time to write but the remaining take longer when compared to having the producer function just write the data.